# Javascript comparing current date to a timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, scala, date, playframework

I'm using the Scala Play framework and I have a form that lets a user search for records, they can then search using today's date and a time stamp `2016-12-17T09:26:47.676Z` to create a search range. Note that I mean a 24 hour period, as a single day is usually defined, and not as a difference in a date definition.

I don't have any experience with Javascript, I'd like to compare today's date with this time stamp, calculate the difference in days, and then return the amount of whole `days` between the two time stamps e.g if the two timestamps had 48 hours difference then it would return `2` days.

I can declare the search time stamp in the `script` tag on the HTML page, but I would like to know how to call today's date, do some logic to calculate the difference between the dates `DaysDifference`, and then call this variable in a link on the page:

`<a target="_blank" href="@baseLogsUrl/#/discover?_g=(time:(from:no@DaysDifference/d,to:now))&_a=(query:(query_string:(query:'@data._id')))">`

Comment: Duplicate of [*How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)? You should define what a day is: a 24 hour period, or change in date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the difference between the current date and a timestamp with the Date API like this: `Date.now() - Date.parse('2016-12-17T09:26:47.676Z')`. This will return the difference in milliseconds, so we can divide the answer by the number of milliseconds in a day to obtain the difference in days. Summarizing:

```
var MS_IN_A_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var difference = Date.now() - Date.parse('2016-12-17T09:26:47.676Z');
var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference/MS_IN_A_DAY);
```

Comment: It may be good to create Date objects and zero the hours. Where daylight saving is observed, there are days with more than 24 hours and some less. Also, from 23:50 on one day to 00:15 the following day may be required to be one day (or not).